# When a XtraForm is maximized, other forms are also affected

Tags: c#, devexpress, maximize-window

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with Devexpress 15.1 Demo version. I'm developing my graduate project. When I maximize any XtraForm, other XtraForms are also affecting and all of them has been maximized. Further if I make WindowState to Normal, all of them goes to Normal State. I have a XtraForm called BaseForm, and I create a new Form by inheriting BaseForm. Forms are not interdependent.

1- I set into the BaseForm Load Event -  WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;  Failure.

2- I set into the Inherited Forms - WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;  Failure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some sample code?

Comment: Thansk for reply. I dont use any state code into the BaseForm or others. I calling the form as;  XtraForm1 f = new XtraForm1();
            f.MdiParent = this;
            f.Show();

Comment: Please review this video https://youtu.be/zEQhj1ovq1M

Comment: probably XtraForm has its own `WindowState` Property. Like `XtraFrom.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal`

Comment: Yes that true, its default value "Normal" but why do other forms get the same state value when I change the state value of a form?

Comment: @BurakH. Without any code it is small chance that we can help you. Post the code where you call your Childform and maybe the code of your BaseForm.

Comment: I captured a new video including codes about this problem. Would you please watch it? https://youtu.be/0_j0GLQsvHQ Thank you all for interesting.

Comment: Could it be a bug of DevExpress?

Comment: From the looks of your code. You seem to be calling the same Form `f` then clicking it to maximize. Every form you opened named `f` will also behave similarly. Even if you instantiate in as `new` its still the same form. Try to make another form and open it using the `button2`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. It gives same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set

> f.MdiParent = this;

on each form.

Comment: I think that your form is not meant to be MdiContainer and this generates unnecessary behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Windows behavior. All Mdi child forms share the same WindowState. Minimizing one minimizes them all (and vice-versa).

Your options are to either not use an Mdi display or to use a tabbed Mdi display, in which case all forms will be maximized and displayed as tabs (similar to a web browser). Additionally, you could handle the Mdi child's FormClosing event and set its WindowState property to Normal, which would then reset all other child Mdi windows to a Normal WindowState.